# Running multiple processes through shell script

Tags: bash, shell, process, background-process

I have a server executable `myserver`. I have to start 5 instances of it with different IP addresses (provided through commandline). This is what I have tried:

```
for i in `seq 1 5`
do
    ip="127.0.0.$i"
    myserver $ip
done
```

The problem is that after starting first myserver, the control does not come to the terminal. How can I start the processes in background?

Appending with `&` i.e. `myserver $ip &` did not help. Most likely, I am doing something wrong with the last `&` that is used to run processes in background.

Edit: `myserver` has to continuously listen to a socket bound to its IP and a default port. Therefore, it has an infinite loop inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in {1..5}
do
    ip="127.0.0.$i"
    myserver "$ip" &
done

wait # for all backgrounded jobs to finish
```

Comment: The `wait` at the end is classy. :) but may be optional